# how to recursively remove embedded carriage return in filenames

Tags: shell, zsh, rename

Is there a way to recursively remove a carriage return \r character that has been appended to thousands file names across a hierarchy of dozens of folders? Also, not all files were affected.

For example, the ls command shows Cymbal2.wav?, where the ? is a \r character.

I'm running MacOS, so if this not the right forum...

Answer (score 7):

A variation on [@Gilles' answer](/a/678761) that removes *all* CR characters in (non-hidden) file names wherever they are.

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv $'(**/)(*\r*)' $'$1${2//\r}'
```

(from within the top-level directory where those files are).

Here, we don't want to use `$f` as it's important we only change the name of the files and not other pathname components as `mv $'a\rb/c\rd' ab/cd` wouldn't work. We need first to do `mv $'a\rb/c\rd' $'a\rb/cd'` and then `mv $'a\rb' ab` which `zmv` does as it processes recursive globs *depth first* (adds the `(#qoD)` qualifier).

`$1` and `$2` above recall what is captured by the `(...)`s in the pattern, so `$1` has the dirname, and `$2` the basename.

Answer (score 6):

For mass-renaming (or mass-copying) files, [`zmv`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) is your friend.

```
autoload zmv
zmv -W $'**/*\r' '**/*'
```

Explanations:

- `zmv` renames files matching the given wildcard pattern (here `$'**/*\r'`) to the given replacement expression (here `**/*`).
- The `-W` option allows wildcards in the replacement expression.
- The [`$'…'` syntax](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-quoting) supports backslash expressions such as `\r` for a carriage return.
- `**/*` matches every file at any level under the current directory (`**` is for [recursive globbing](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing).

Alternatively:

```
autoload zmv
zmv $'**/*\r' $'${f%\r}'
```

`$f` stands for the original file name and the `${VARIABLE%SUFFIX}` [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) form strips off the given suffix.

Recommendation for your `.zshrc`:

```
autoload zmv
alias zcp='zmv -C'
alias zln='zln -L'
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comment this works on Linux but not by default on MacOS.

```
touch $'file_\r_name'

ls -l --quoting-style=c file_*
-rw-r--r-- 1 hl hauke 0 23. Nov 17:02 "file_\r_name"

find . -name $'*\r*' -exec rename -nv $'\r' '' {} + 2>/dev/null | cat -v
`./file_^M_name' -> `./file__name'
```

`-nv` puts `rename` in verbose dry run mode.

`cat -v` is (more or less) necessary because the `\r` makes the output look quite strange (because the part after the `\r` overwrites the part before).

Comment: It should perhaps be noted that it's the util-linux version of `rename` that's used here, not the Perl one. `rename -n -v 's/\r$//' {} + ` should work with the Perl one.

Comment: This would work on Linux, but the asker specified macOS, where util-linux `rename` is definitely not available. A perl rename may be available from a popular package source; Homebrew has one, but it's not the same as rename/prename on Debian.